# Getting back the object from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I can send an object via model from a controller to a jsp page, but how to get that object back to the controller, after saving some data to it?

My form looks like this:

```
    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user" action="/GENEPI/userChangePassword" commandName="user">      
                        <spring:message code="label.newPassword" />
                        <br>
                        <input id="password" type="password"
                            pattern=".{8,30}" class="input-block-level"
                            onFocusOut="passwordValidation();"
                            title="ERROR" />
            </form:form>
```

And my controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userChangePassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String changePasswordPOST(@ModelAttribute("user") UserEntity user,
        @ModelAttribute("newPassword") String newPassword, Model model) {
    System.out.println("USERNAME: " + user.getUsername());

}
```

Nevertheless `user` is always `null`. How to make it to pass that `user` object from jsp to controller with the data user has filled there?

edit: with other words - is there some way, how to fill in the `model` map with pairs key-value from `jsp` page and post it then back to `controller`?

Comment: Spring is not Spring MVC.

Comment: yes, true, my bad..On the other hand Spring MVC framework is a subset of Spring framework, so I don't see anything wrong on adding here a `Spring` tag..

Comment: While Spring MVC is part of Spring, `[spring]` tag is used for spring core questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you use spring taglib `form` and hidden into i.e. `table`, something like that:

```
<table align="center" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: -20px; width: 100%">
  <tr>
   <td width="40%" class="">
    <form:label path="user">Username: </form:label></td>
   <td width="60%" class="">
    <form:input path="usuario" cssClass="" readonly="true"/></td>
  </tr>
    <form:hidden path="password" id="pwdDB" />
  <tr>
   <td width="40%" class="">
    <form:label path="password">Password: </form:label></td>
   <td width="60%" class=""><form:password path="" id="password" cssClass="" maxlength="14"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><form:hidden path="username" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><form:hidden path="otherattributePOJO" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><form:hidden path="anotherattributePOJO" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And you put attribute from your POJO onto `path`.

**I hope help you :)**

Comment: @Dworza your Question initiallly was how to get object back from JSP.For this I suggested you to use data binding using spring form tags.Your Question explicitly said "how to get that object back to the controller, after saving some data to it?"...Also you said "How to make it to pass that user object from jsp to controller with the data user has filled there?"...and The input element with a type attribute whose value is "hidden" represents a value that is not intended to be examined or manipulated by the user...It would be great if you could tell me how using hidden tags solved your problem.

Comment: @Niks: because I didn't use the hidden tag, the values in the returned object, with which I didn't work in the form, were set to null. Now when I use `hidden` for those with which I don't work with, I get back object with all values..

Comment: @Dworza So you mean Hidden fields sets the values of  the object to some default value automatically?Its quite confusing the way you put the Question.

Comment: No, they don't set some deafault value, but keep the value, that was there before...If I don't don't put those hidden forms there, the original values are deleted after confirming the form...or better - deleted are only those with which I don't currently work with in that form

Answer (score 1):

A `jsp` gets rendered as HTML which is sent as the body of an HTTP response to some client.

There is no concept of Object in HTML. What you are doing with the form is serializing some input fields as request parameters and sending those in a new HTTP request. In this case, you are sending a POST.

Spring's uses an interface called [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) to construct arguments for your `@Controller` handler methods. It uses an implementation called [`ModelAttributeMethodProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html) to resolve parameters that have the `@ModelAttribute` annotation. The javadoc states

> Model attributes are obtained from the model or if not found possibly
>   created with a default constructor if it is available. Once created,
>   the attributed is populated with request data via data binding and
>   also validation may be applied if the argument is annotated with
>   @javax.validation.Valid.

In other words, if you don't have an attribute in the model that is accessible through a named key (`@ModelAttribute` `value` attribute value), Spring will construct it from request parameters whose names are equal to the names of your Class' fields. In this case, there are none.

If you want Spring to serialize a `UserEntity` object for you, you need to put `input` fields in the form that have the same `name` attribute value as the `UserEntity` class fields, and give those inputs a value, probably the ones it had previously.

Take a look at the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib) for Spring's tag libraries.

Comment: I don't do Spring MVC but I though that's what Spring MVC could do for you to leverage development instead of passing `HttpServletRequest request` on every method and do `request.getParameter` manually.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't know and I wasn't able to seek out, how to put there that atribute from the jsp side, if you know, what I mean..

Comment: @dworza If you want Spring to serialize a `UserEntity` object for you, you need to put `input` fields in the form that have the same `name` attribute value as the `UserEntity` class fields, and give those `inputs` a value, probably the ones it had previously.

Comment: @dworza [Here's a pretty complete example.](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-form-handling/)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Examples are long to write :(. I linked one instead.

Comment: I've pasted a bad part of code from where is probably not certain, what I do there... When I access that view, I put to a model a UserEntity object, in that view I work with it and then I want to pass it to another controller..just unchanged in that state in which that view has received it..but the value of the object is null :-/

Comment: @Dworza If you want to persist an object accross requests, it might be better to think of flash attributes (session scope). Look that up, it is another subject altogether.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I haven't read the whole example, but IMO as a starter, I would decline to learning Spring MVC with that example =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza If you have a small understanding of how to setup a spring-mvc project, the tutorial should be easy to follow. Why do you say the contrary? (gtg, I'll bbl)

Comment: IMO doing lot of configurations (even if they're plain copy/paste from the tutorial) to start doing **the work** is something I won't follow. I like to [keep things simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) in order to do **the work**,

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I would normally agree with you but the tutorial I linked has 2 configuration classes which are required (one to replace web.xml and one to setup Spring IoC container) and the `pom.xml` dependencies. You cannot have less than that as configuration for a Spring project.

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses the concept of Data Binding if you use it with Spring Form tag.

Check this link:
[Using Spring Form Library](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib)

The logic is you pass your Bean or Model to JSP,user will enter the values and then the model is passed to the controller.
You have to use @ModelAttribute to get the Model and then after you have got the model you can use it.

I see two mistakes in your JSP and Controlller.
1.You have used the modelAttribute and commandName on the same Model ie. user.
Either user modelAttribute or commandName.

2.There is no Model named as newPassword in your JSP and you are trying to get it in your Controller.

3.I assume that this User Bean has property of Password which you are trying to set it from JSP.So you have to get that User Bean not the individual property.

Let me know if  you still have doubt.

Comment: If I understood it well, then I can add to my jsp something like `<form:input path="newPassword" />` and then access it via  `@ModelAttribute("newPassword")` from my controller? to 2) you're right - that's the point. I don't know, how to pass the value to the controller 3) I don't want to store `newPassword` in my `UserEntity`, because it would cause mess in the database layer then.

Comment: ..and I don't think that it's worth to implement special bean only for storing one property. There must be some other way, how to pass just one String to controller, isn't it?

Comment: @Dworza There must be some object to which the fields can be bound in the request. So you need to pass an Object(you can call it bean,model or whatever) to the jsp which is filled with user data and then returned to the controller.If your form has only one field then I would ask you is it worthy to have only one field in the form?If you have other fields ,then you don't have to create a new bean just add one more variable to that already existing bean and extract the data later.

Comment: @Dworza and from your first comment I assume that you are passing your pojo object(the one which is used to do mapping with DB) directly to your controller which is a bad Practice as it is coupling your code and this the reason you are having hard time adding one more variable to it.If this is true then I suggest you to change your design if possible.

Comment: actually I just missed the fact, that the old password value in my UserEntity will not be used any more, so I can store that value in it and if validation on backend will end without any error, then I can save it via hibernate to dtb :)

Answer (score -1):

The basic idea is that using a HTTP Post, you are usually setting your input data to Strings or primitive data types and the data will be posted to a servlet.

This basic idea remains the same for all of the frameworks which extend the basic http framework.  E.g. Struts, Spring MVC, StripesFramework etc.

I suggest that you get comfortable with how HTTP works.

In your particular case the key information for looking up the user should also be able to be posted back to the servlet either by having the user eneter the user information (usually userid/password) or be storing the information as a hidden field.